# Symfony form.vars.data vs form.vars.value

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

A FormView object in Symfony contains several variables, that can be accessed via twig using the public `vars` property.

Two of those variables are `value` and `data`.

So, supposing that we have our `form` variable in twig, we can access them using `form.vars.data` and `form.vars.value`.

The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-variables-reference) is clear about the meaning of those properties:

- **value**: The value that will be used when rendering (commonly the value HTML attribute).
- **data**: The normalized data of the type.

but when I use `{{ dump(form.vars) }}` and compare `form.vars.value` and `form.vars.data` they look like identical. Why? What's the correct meaning and proper usage of those two properties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take for example a DateType field.

Here, `value` would be something like the string `2016-06-10`.
`data` on the other hand would be a corresponding `DateTime`-Object.

When using Text fields, you will not see any difference because in both cases there will be just a string.