# value vs. data in Symfony Forms - What is the difference and how to control the content?

Tags: forms, symfony

what is the difference between the two fields `data` and `value` in Symfony Forms?

I have created a custom `Form Type` for my custom `Task` class which works fine in all my forms. To understand the internal workflow behind form better, I have observed the operation by adding some `{{ dump(...) }}`statements to my Twig files.

In all my forms the `value` and `data` fields of my `Task` type both hold the same information: A reference to the `Task` object.

However I have recognized, that some third party Form Types have different values for the two `value` and `data` fields: While the `data` fields holds a reference the underlying object the `value` field just contains an ID of this object (member field of the object). How is this achieved?

- What exactly is the purpose of these two fields?
- What is the difference between them?
- How do I control/chance the content of
  `value` field while still having the object reference in the `data`
  field?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744820/symfony-form-vars-data-vs-form-vars-value)