# Twig can dump a not null object, but indicates the variable is null when trying to dump an attribute or a method of the same object

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony3.x

I have an abstract entity class `Person` which is used to store in a same table different type of person (employee, freelance, ...) using a DiscriminatorMap.
The different entity classes (`Employee`, `Freelance`,...) then extends the abstract `Person` class.

Properties are protected properties.
Getter and setters method are public methods defined in the `Person` abstract class.

I have a `Team` entity class which contains an ArrayCollection of `Employee` entities.

In order to render the FormType used to manages the team (a CollectionType of Employee), I created a block in the Twig template to render the ArrayCollection item (a widget to render the collection item fields)

In this block, if I do :

```
{% set person = form.vars.value %}
{{ dump(person) }}
```

I get a perfect dump of an existing instance of member

```
Employee {#942 ▼
  #team: Team {#700 ▶}
  #id: 85
  #role: "Coffee Maker"
```

But if I try to access a property :

```
{% set person = form.vars.value %}
{{ dump(person.role) }}
```

I get a Twig_Error_Runtime : `"Impossible to access an attribute ("role") on a null variable."`

And if I try to call a getter method :

```
{% set person = form.vars.value %}
{{ dump(person.getRole()) }}
```

I get a Twig_Error_Runtime : `Impossible to invoke a method ("getRole") on a null variable.`

When watching the error message, I see this call :

When trying to access the property : 
`Twig_Template->getAttribute(null, 'role', array())`

When trying to call a getter method :
`Twig_Template->getAttribute(null, 'getRole', array(), 'method')`

How could it be null since the first `{{ dump(person) }}` showed all the entity properties ?

I've tried by setting the Person abstract class properties as public, and I've tried by replacing ´form.vars.value´ by ´form.vars.data´ but I keep getting the same errors.

This is really strange, because if I try to render the fields of the Form, it works perfectly (and the value is well setted)

```
{{ form_widget(form.team) }}
{{ form_widget(form.role) }}
```

What did I miss ?
Any tip to solve that issue is welcome. Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Twig will try to execute the `get`, `is`, `has` as a prefix method of the attribute name you passed.  However you should be using `form.vars.data` when accessing an object from the Symfony form view.   See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744820/symfony-form-vars-data-vs-form-vars-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony form.vars.data vs form.vars.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744820/symfony-form-vars-data-vs-form-vars-value)

Comment: I have the same behaviour (same error) when using form.vars.data instead of form.vars.values. :-/

Comment: Please post your `controller` that renders the form view, the `FormType` of the form, and your `Employee` class.